# django doesn't save manytomany object

Tags: python, django

I have this models

```
class Base(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    district = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s__Game_Owner')
    attending = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    requested = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="%(class)s__requested")
    invited = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="%(class)s__invited")
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Hash = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
```

and I have other two classes inherting from this base. The class names are 
reservation and enlisting
I created this function in the views

```
def test_join_event(event_id, event_type, user_id):
    event = None
    if event_type =='enlisting':
        event = enlistings.objects.get(id=event_id)           
    elif event_type =='reservation':
        event = reservations.objects.get(id=event_id)

    requested_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    if requested_user == event.Owner:
        return "Error: you are already part of the event"
    if requested_user in event.players.all():
        return "Error 2!"
    if requested_user in event.invited.all():
        return "You are already invited to the event!"
    if requested_user in event.requested.all():
        return "You can't send your request again!"

    event.requested.add(requested_user)
    event.save()
    return "Saved!!"
```

when I call the function from the interpreter it keeps giving me "Saved" however it should add the user to the requested list and the next time I call the function it returns "You can't send your request again" !!! 
I tried the function from the browser it returns saved too, but when I look at the object in the interpreter I see that the requsted list is empty (doesn't have the player I just added)

When I checekd from the interpreter I got the same problem!! I only noticed that I only can add the user who owns that event. 
for example like this code

```
event.requested.add(event.owner)
event.requested.all() # The user is added successfully !!
```

I can't understand why this is happening. Any ideas??

Comment: Any help with this situation ?? definitely there is a solution !!

Comment: you don't need `event.save()` as adding to a many-to-many relation happens immediately

Comment: The addition of the many-to-many relation is not happening actually. !!